# I want to store the data in an array from the web api

Tags: javascript

I want to use values from the web api , everything is running fine but when I read values from the url in a single variable it comes as large data:

```js
var orguni = "http://hospdev.hispindia.org/haryana_220/api/organisationUnits?fields=name,id,code";
           
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: orguni,
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    headers: {
    },
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find('organisationUnit ').each(function () {
            var ou = $(this).attr('id');
        
            console.log("UID:  "+ ou);
        });
    }
});
```

Now when I display `ou` it returns a list of different id's and I want to use all id's as separate value, can anybody tell me how to do that.

```
Currently it returns:

index.html:26 UID:  g8cMOWx5ydN
index.html:26 UID:  Q2FEgPgHvMr
index.html:26 UID:  XpIf2v7cJRX
index.html:26 UID:  uoPA7guOuLa
index.html:26 UID:  BLpdsMuZcqD
```

When I use console.log(ou[0]); it returns 1st char from each like:

```
g
Q
x
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];    
$(xml).find('organisationUnit ').each(function () {
    var ou = $(this).attr('id');
    array.push(ou); 
});
```

array[0] will now be g8cMOWx5ydN.

What ou[0] is doing is turning g8cMOWx5ydN into an array and returning index 0, which is 'g'.

**Edit Following Comment**

you can either use the Id as you retrieve it, and not use the array.

```
$(xml).find('organisationUnit ').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // use id ajax call here
});
```

or you can use the array after the each

```
var array = [];    
$(xml).find('organisationUnit ').each(function () {
   var ou = $(this).attr('id');
   array.push(ou); 
});

//other code

for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   var id = array[i];

   // use id ajax call here
}
```

Comment: thanks , it works like a butter, Now one last thing can you please tell me if I want to use these array element values in another ajax then how I can do that? I have tried using global declaration but didn't worked

Comment: if this helped then an upvote/mark as answered would be appreciated.